# How can I import the same classes from a package

Tags: java, android, jar, import

I have ajar file which contains the package `org.apache` with a lot of different classes like Socket... When I include this Jar into my project, it rather uses (imports) the existing java package "org.apache" and not the one from my Jar. I can state, that I added the jar in `libs` directory. How can I ensure that my custom classes from the jar package are used (instead the java classes).

Do not hesitate to ask if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath specifies an *order* for the JARs and directories that are searched.  If the real apache JAR is ahead of your JAR on the classpath, then the class loader will look in the real JAR file first.  And if it finds a class there it will use that version instead of your version.

> How can I ensure that my custom classes from the jar package ... ?

Make sure that it is at the start of the classpath.

---

Since you are doing this with Android and Eclipse, you need to do the dependencies "the android way".  According to my reading of ["Dealing with dependencies in Android projects"](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects), you will need to put the Apache JAR file into a "Library Project" insteal of the libs directory.  The page I linked to implies that your current project's `lib/*.jar` files automatically come first on the classpath ... and it doesn't say that you can change that.

---

It should be stated that putting alternate versions of Apache classes into your project is **"a horrible hack"** and it doesn't *deserve* to work.  The correct procedure is:

- If those Apache classes are part of the Android platform, then don't change them at all!
- Otherwise, clone the relevant Apache source tree, make your changes to it, rebuild the Apache JAR, and use that JAR instead.

Comment: so, how can i set order in my eclipse.

Comment: But when i trying to create library project...it does same thing, because it also have android jar...

Comment: Means to say it also consist java libraries...

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  Did you put the Apache JAR in the Library Project?  Did you add the Library Project as a dependency for your project

Comment: No. I didn't do this but i want to say that... I have amazons3 jar file which have apache package and i want to use this package but i am unable to import this package...when i tried to import, will automatically import java apache package...so how can i use this.

Comment: Try doing what I suggested.  Put the JAR that contains the (real) Apache classes into a Library Project.  AFAIK, this is the only thing that is likely to work.  If it doesn't work then you will need to modify or rebuild that JAR file.

Comment: By the way, you've not bothered to say what the real problem is.  Why are you replacing Apache classes?  What is the point?

Comment: There have some modification with new apache classes like Socket configuration, Certificate issues when you trying to make connection and many things.

Comment: Thnx.... it worked....

Comment: Everything works fine but when i build project i got this problem in eclipse : "Errors running builder 'Scanner Configuration Builder' on project"

Comment: I've no idea.  Ask a new Question.  (And PLEASE try to explain the problem clearly.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your IDE. In eclipse you can set the order of the referenced files (JAR, classes).
If you execute your tool from the command line, add the files in "ascending" order to the `-cp` flag.

Otherwise give us more details.

Comment: so, how can i set order in my eclipse.

Comment: Right click on your project: Properties > (in the tree) Java Build Path > (Tab) Order and Export.  Do you mind upvoting my answer?